# how to store values in list to more than one variable ( in python django )

Tags: python, django, loops

I have some list values like ..

```
test_list = ["grandfathers", "name", "is","John"]
```

I want to put all the index value before "is" to one variable ...and store all index values after "is" to another variable

for an example ,

```
value1 = "grandfathers name"
value2 = "John"
```

the index position of "is sometime change , and total number of index in test_list also not always same , so I need a solution which applicable in any situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list `index()` to get index of `'is'` and do slicing:

```
before = ' '.join(test_list[:test_list.index('is')])
after = ' '.join(test_list[test_list.index('is')+1:])
```